# Testosterone level in body with activites

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, endocrinology

Does ejaculation lower level of testosterone in body, Conflicting reports on internet, a firm answer would help a lot?

Answer (score 0):

There are two studies that shows that level of testosterone is higher during abstinence.

[A research on the relationship between ejaculation and serum testosterone level in men](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12659241?dopt=Abstract):

> The authors found that the fluctuations of testosterone levels from the 2nd to 5th day of abstinence were minimal. On the 7th day of abstinence, however, a clear peak of serum testosterone appeared, reaching 145.7% of the baseline ( P < 0.01). No regular fluctuation was observed following continuous abstinence after the peak.
>
> ...
>
> The results showed that ejaculation-caused variations were characterized by a peak on the 7th day of abstinence; and that the effective time of an ejaculation is 7 days minimum.

[Endocrine response to masturbation-induced orgasm in healthy men following a 3-week sexual abstinence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11760788?dopt=Abstract):

> These effects were observed both before and after sexual abstinence. In contrast, although plasma testosterone was unaltered by orgasm, higher testosterone concentrations were observed following the period of abstinence. These data demonstrate that acute abstinence does not change the neuroendocrine response to orgasm but does produce elevated levels of testosterone in males.